# Change background color of WPF DataGrid Top Left Corner Header

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am working on a Visual Studio extension and trying to theme a WPF DataGrid to match the Visual Studio light or dark theme. I have managed to get everything working except for the top left corner of the DataGrid.

[image: DataGrid]

In Silverlight, this is called the TopLeftCornerHeader, but I cannot figure out how to change the background color in WPF.

So far, I have modified the DataGrid like this,

```
<DataGrid 
    Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static wpf:Theme.BackgroundKey}}"
    Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static wpf:Theme.ForegroundKey}}"
    RowBackground="{DynamicResource {x:Static wpf:Theme.BackgroundKey}}"
    AlternatingRowBackground="{DynamicResource {x:Static wpf:Theme.BackgroundAccentKey}}" 
    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static wpf:Theme.ControlBorderKey}}"
    VerticalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static wpf:Theme.ControlBorderKey}}"
    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static wpf:Theme.ControlBorderKey}}" >
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static wpf:Theme.BackgroundKey}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: Please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30099602/579817 or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25143513/579817 answers for a solution if you need row headers to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the only ways to be setting for `DataGrid` *`RowHeaderWidth`*:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
          RowHeaderWidth="0" 
          ... />
```

I tried to set [`RowHeaderStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowheaderstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`RowHeaderTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowheadertemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but they do not affect the area in the upper left corner.

It may also be `PART_LeftHeaderGripper` thumb which is located in `DataGridColumnHeader`, it is just to the left in the header column:

```
<Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper"
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       Style="{StaticResource Style_HeaderGripper}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been banging my head against this for days. It is less than perfect, but I set the RowHeaderWidth and then added some left margin to the first column and it looks good enough to ship :)