# xaml style all datagrid 'select all' buttons in specific style name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141573/how-to-style-the-top-left-corner-of-a-datagrid-in-xaml), to style a data grids top left corner (the select all button), I can do something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, 
  TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFf2f2f2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 0, 1, 0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFf9f9f9"/>
</Style>
```

The thing is, I do not want this style globally, but I do want to be able to re-use this style. I know I could copy/paste it into specific data grids, but I would prefer to keep it reusable. Is this possible, by somehow applying a property to the datagrid?

Comment: You would have to rename your custom `Button` `Style` by setting `x:key` to a specific name, let's say `x:Key="SelectAllButtonStyle1">` and then create a `DataGrid` style that uses it.

Comment: But the x:key atteibute is already in use for ComponentResourceKey in order to specify the datagridselectallbutton? I cannot specify both I don't think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication276.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication276"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">

<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
           x:Key="SelectAllButtonStyle1">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFf2f2f2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 0, 1, 0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF688CAF"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                            <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" Style="{DynamicResource SelectAllButtonStyle1}" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                        <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}" />
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

---

You can also make it a little less verbose by customizing only the datagrid's `Template`:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
           x:Key="SelectAllButtonStyle1">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFf2f2f2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 0, 1, 0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                <ScrollViewer.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" Style="{DynamicResource SelectAllButtonStyle1}" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                            <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ScrollViewer.Template>
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

And then similarly applying it like before:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
                  Template="{DynamicResource ControlTemplate1}" />
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />
    </StackPanel>
```