# how to change the background color of the datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, background-color

how do i changing the color of my datagrid i have the color i wan't in the designer but when i debuging it 
it just changing back to default white
i had tryed with this

```
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF303030"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
```

but that didn't worked

Comment: It could possibly be that you're defining it elsewhere and it's overriding. Do you have it set directly in your DataGrid declaration too? e.g. `<DataGrid Background="someothercolor"/>`

Comment: yes i also tryed with that

Comment: If it's still there in the declaration you need to remove it or the style you posted in your question won't be applied. You want to make sure you're only setting it once. I'll post an answer showing what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just define the background color once. If you're also setting it in the DataGrid declaration it will override the style.

e.g. in this first example I'm explicitly setting the background to red in the declaration, so it ignores the color in the style. Result = red background

```
    <DataGrid Background="Red">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
```

Whereas if I remove the color from the declaration it will pick up the color from the style. In this second example you will see a green background.

```
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
```

Note that the `Background` for the `DataGrid` is the color behind the cells (you might not even see it if your `DataGrid` is full of data). You might also want to set styles for `DataGridRow`, `DataGridRowHeader` and `DataGridColumnHeader` if you want to change those colors. I've also included the style to set the top-left corner select all button which is a little trickier, taken from [Style datagrid table - Top left corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328328/style-datagrid-table-top-left-corner/30099602#30099602)

```
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: If this doesn't fix it please update your question with the full xaml source for your DataGrid so we can see what else might be happening.

Comment: yeah it was due to the row are there a way to change the color of the small clickable squares(not sure what they are called) that are in the left cornor

Comment: Moved the additional styles to the answer